# Launch youtube app with a video on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, youtube, playback

I need to do this: I have an app with a button, I wish, when I click the button that the iPhone launch youtube app with directly my video ready to start to play..
I've tried this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=my_video_id"]];
```

but launch safari in the video page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really should work if the button is a UIButton in a native Cocoa Touch app. Is yours an HTML button in a UIWebView?

Comment: hi Mattew... now seems to work but actually the problem is another....
the video link is this: http://www.youtube.com/v/Z7Sw5OtTHAc and seems to have problems with UMG, but on youtube on my mac works fine... any ideas about this?

thanks

Comment: YouTube should automatically switch to HTML5/H.264 mode when it senses that the visitor is using an iOS device. Perhaps there's a setting you can change on YouTube to make sure it sends HTML5 video (I looked for a couple of my videos and didn't see the option, but I might have missed it).

Comment: I think that the problem is the music... it's possible? but is strange that loads on youtube webpage but directly not...